# Java Generics: Incompatible types: capture<? extends Object> and <? extends T>

Tags: java, generics

I have an object of type T (generic)

```
public <T> void method1(T object) {...}
```

I want to use the method getClass() on that object.

```
Class<? extends T> clazz = object.getClass();
```

but the compiler shows error:

```
Incompatible types.
Found:    'java.lang.Class<capture<? extends java.lang.Object>>'
Required: 'java.lang.Class<? extends T>'
```

How can I correct my code so that the compiler will compile, and the clazz object will have generic type T, or <? extends T> without casting ?

Comment: Your method needs to accept an extra `Class<? extends T>` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugly-cast is the only way:

```
Class<? extends T> clazz = (Class<? extends T>) object.getClass();
```

... and then suppress the warning that you get when you do this using `@SuppressWarnings`.

More generally, it's almost always a mistake to even want the Class object. Perhaps expand on why you think you need it, there is probably a nicer alternative.

For actual types, the code works fine (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())), but not for typevars:

> The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:

The 'erasure of the static type' is just `Object` for your specific `T` here, hence, you get `Class<? extends Object>`, which is just `Class<?>`, which you can't assign to a variable of type `Class<? extends T>` unless you ugly-cast. Why does it work this way? Eh, it does, spec says so. I admit I don't know why, but it is what it is.

NB: You could also add a parameter: `void foo(Class<? extends T> clazz, T value)` but now you're bothering callers with passing a seemingly useless additional parameter. Probably not a good idea. The compiler will at least check your callers and complain if they pass e.g. `String.class` and then pass an integer as a value.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answer, the reason that `.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends |X|>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called, is that `X` might be a parameterized type, and it is unsafe to have a `Class<a parameterized type>` or a `Class<? extends a parameterized type>`.

For example, consider `Class<ArrayList<String>>`. But there's actually only a single `Class` instance representing `ArrayList` -- it is not specific for `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Integer>`, etc. If you had an expression of type `Class<ArrayList<String>>`, you could call `.cast()` on it and pass any object and get an `ArrayList<String>` without warnings, but that would be deceptive, because it didn't really check that the object is an `ArrayList<String>` (there's no way to do that at runtime); it only checked that it was an `ArrayList`; you may still get a nasty surprise down the line if it's an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Similarly, with a `Class<ArrayList<String>>`, you could call `.isInstance()` on it and pass an `ArrayList<Integer>` and get `true`.

The same thing is true for a `Class<? extends ArrayList<String>>`; i.e. you could call `.cast()` on it and get an `ArrayList<String>`, and you could call `.isInstance()` on it, and get deceptive results. Those are unsafe. So you should not be able to get type `Class<? extends ArrayList<String>>` without a warning. Since in your code it's possible for `T` to be a parameterized type (the compiler must assume that a type variable can be any type that is within its bounds), the compiler can't give you a `Class<? extends T>` without a warning. It must return a type known at compile time to be safe, and the option chosen by the language designers is `Class<? extends |T|>`, which in your case is `Class<? extends Object>`.

Comment: <T>.getClass() returns Class<T> by definition.
<T<X>>.getClass() returns Class<T<?>> due to erasure.

But that's not the case there, since T isn't parameterized.

Comment: @ZdeněkPavlas: The JLS defines `<some expression of type T>.getClass()` to return type `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `|T|` is the erasure of `T`. I am not sure what you mean by `<T>.getClass()`. Is `T` the name of a class? or a type variable? If `T` is a type variable, then it could represent any type, including a parameterized type like `ArrayList<String>`. Therefore, returning `Class<T>` or `Class<? extends T>` would be incorrect.